# Import Drupal 8 Database in MAMP using PHP Myadmin

Tags: importing-exporting

I'm trying to import a drupal 8 database to my local MAMP server via phpmyadmin.

I have a 1.4MB database.sql.gz file (cache emptied, it doens't matter what database export of drupal 8 I use by the way).  But I keep getting an internal server error. Looking at the log I find this:

```
InnoDB: Error: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table "databasename"."tablename" but the required system tables mysql.innodb_table_stats and mysql.innodb_index_stats are not present or have unexpected structure. Using transient stats instead.
```

Followed by:

```
InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.
```

So my settings must be off, but I don't know what to change? Can some help me with fixing this.

Thanks in advance,
Joost

Comment: Did you try to import it with drush ?
drush sql-cli < /path/to/your/db.sql

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54608/innodb-error-table-mysql-innodb-table-stats-not-found-after-upgrade-to-mys